# How to use buf cli to check breaking changes against one file

Tags: protocol-buffers, buf

[Buf](https://docs.buf.build/introduction) is a tool to make Protobuf reliable and user friendly for service owners and clients. Has anyone tried using ***buf breaking*** command against one single file to detect any breaking changes for that proto file? The buf doc only mentions running that command against a sub directory and I am wondering if we can run that command against one single file. Thanks.

Comment: Could you find out anything, yet?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.buf.build/breaking/usage#limit-to-specific-files is probably what you're looking for, although it's not recommended — from the docs:

> it is better to let buf discover all files under management and handle this for you in general, especially when using the FILE category.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).